# How to add a file path reference inside javascript comment?

Tags: javascript, file, url, comments, filepath

Given the following code...

```
function foo() {
  // Look at "./image.png" for reference.
}
```

Is there a standard way to write `"./image.png"` so that when the text is clicked (or ctrl clicked) — using an IDE — the file `image.png` opens either in an external image editor or inside the IDE itself ?

I'm looking for a solution that works with Webstorm and VSCode.